# Python script to create a falling and constant line with an overall mean as boundary condition

Tags: python, geometry, linear-algebra

I have a timespan t1 and a timespan t2.
I want a linear falling curve during t1 and constant line for t2.
The transition between the lines shall be continuous. The falling curve starts at (0,0).
Also the boundary condition must be satisfied, that the overall mean of the two lines is b.
t1, t2, b are given. How to calculate the lines in python?

My code looks the following, but the overall mean does not match the given mean "mean".

```
# Given Parameters
t1 = 460
t2 = 920
mean = -0.34

a = (0.5*t1+t2)*mean/(t1+t2) # Calculate y of constant part
m = a/t1 # slope of the linear part of the line

X = list(range(0, t1+t2, 1)) # Generate line
Y = []
for x in X:
    if x <=t1:
        y = m * x
        Y.append(y)
    else:
        y = a
        Y.append(y)
sum(Y)/len(Y)
plt.plot(X,Y)# Plot
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXKLr.png)

My Idea was to solve the two equations:

1. m = a/t1 (m: slope, a: y-value of constant line)
2. mean = 1/(t1+t2)(integral 0 till t1 of y=mx + integral t1 till t1+t2 of y=a)

Unfortunately there must be some mistake.

I would be very happy about help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `t1, t2, b are given`:

Let constant Y-value is `-p`. Mean value is trapezoid area divided by longer base.

Trapezoid area

```
S = p * (t1 + t2 + t2) / 2 = p/2*(t1+2*t2)
```

Mean

```
b = p/2*(t1+2*t2) / (t1+t2)
```

So

```
p = 2*b*(t1+t2)/(t1+2*t2)
```

And coefficient:

```
m = p/t1
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! There was one small typo in your solution: p = 2*(t1+t2)/(t1+2*t2)*b but the trapezoid idea was great! Thanks!